# Matlab: is there a way to add northarrow and scale bar?

Tags: matlab, elevation

I made a plot of a glacier (see below). I was wondering if there is a way to (a) add a northarrow in the left corner, and (b) add a scale bar (I know the resolution as the coordinate system measures in meters), so for example X = 3.18E5 to X = 3.185E5 is 500m.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `northarrow('latitude', -57, 'longitude', 135);` maybe? If you are using the Mapping toolbox! Check examples [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/north-arrows.html)

Comment: To add a scale also use `scaleruler` [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/scaleruler.html).